# How to stop Pipe in getopt?

Tags: c

I'm trying to run something like this in getopt.

> ./bmptool -s 2 example.bmp | ./bmptool -r 90 -o out.bmp

My code works but I would like to know if there is a way for me to not run this command

> ./bmptool -r 90 -o out.bmp

if something goes wrong when I'm running

> ./bmptool -s 2 example.bmp

The following method is used to catch if a user enters a case that is not present and exits the program if needed. It works when I'm only running one command, but when I chain commands together it stills run the following command giving me some an output that I do not want. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
if (err || optind + 1 < argc) {
    fprintf(stderr, usage, argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with getopt or even C. `foo | bar` tells the shell to run the commands `foo` and `bar` in parallel, with `foo`'s output connected to `bar`'s input. There's nothing you can do because both programs are started immediately.

Comment: Is there no way for me to "catch" it when I'm running the second command? Like if I output something like "quit" in my first command, can I see if that is input when I'm running my second command and exit out of that? Or am I completely misunderstanding piping?

Comment: Sure, you can do that if you control both sides of the pipe.

Comment: You can watch for EOF/error on input, and just write nothing to stdout and exit on error... if the first instance fails and exits, the second will get EOF on stdin and can exit also.

Comment: You probably need something like `if ./bmptool -s 2 example.bmp > out.$$.bmp; then ./bmptool -r 90 -o out.bmp < out.$$.bmp; fi; rm -f out.$$.bmp`, though you might want to be cleverer about intermediate file names (`mktemp`) and cleaning in case of signals (`trap`).